# data not attaching for simple jquery post

Tags: jquery, post

Doing a simple jquery post and my data is not being attached.  selected is perfectly fine before anyone says anything.

this does not work :

```
$('#dtDownload').on('click', function () {

    var data = {
      'selected': selected
    };

    $.post("/process/p_screenshots_download.php", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });

});
```

but doing so with ajax does work :

```
$('#dtDownload').on('click', function () {

    var data = {
      'selected': selected
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/process/p_screenshots_download.php',
        data: data,
        dataType : 'json'
    }).done(function (response) {
    });

});
```

Why is data null for this first example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not attaching the data.

It should be

```
$.post("/process/p_screenshots_download.php", data, function(data, status){
  alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```